# I want to change attributes in CSV file also simultaneously when change in attributes from Admin grid

Tags: magento2

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$_objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$registry = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
$registry->register('isSecureArea', true);
$productRepository = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');


$stockRegistry = $_objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');
$csv = "export.csv";
$store_id = 1;

if(!is_file($csv))
{
    $fp = fopen("export.csv","w+");
    $collection = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory')->create()->addStoreFilter($store_id)->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'simple')->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku','price','qty'));
    foreach ($collection as $product)
    {
        $data = array();
        
        $data[] = $product->getSku();
        $data[] = $product->getPrice();
        $data[] = $product->getQty();
      

        fputcsv($fp, $data);  
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
else
{
    if (!empty($argv) && sizeof($argv) > 1) 
    {
        $csv = $argv[1];
    }
    if (($handle = fopen($csv, "r")) !== FALSE) 
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, "\t")) !== FALSE) 
        {                
        
            $num = count($row);           
            if ($num < 1)
             {
                continue;
             }
            $sku = trim($row[0]);
                 
            if($num < 2) 
            {
                echo "Skipping: " . $sku . " not enough fields\n";
                continue;
            }
             $price = trim($row[1]);
            $qty = trim($row[2]);
            try
             {
                $product = $productRepository->get($sku);                
             }  
            catch (\Exception $e)
             {
                echo "Error:  Invalid SKU, ".$sku."\n"; 
                continue;
             }

            if ($product->getPrice() != $price) 
            {                 
                $product->setPrice($price);        
                $product->save();
            }
            try
            {
                $stockItem = $stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
            } 
            catch (\Exception $e)
             { 
                echo "Error:  Invalid stock SKU, ".$sku."\n";
                continue;
            }

            if ($stockItem->getQty() != $qty)
             { 
                $stockItem->setQty($qty);
                if ($qty > 0) 
                {
                    $stockItem->setIsInStock(1);
                }
                $stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
        
}
```

Comment: Hello, what exactly you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Please share your answer here so that it can help others also.

Answer (score 0):

getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$registry = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
$registry->register('isSecureArea', true);
 $productRepository = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
$stockRegistry = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');

$csvfile = 'export.csv';

$tempfile = tempnam(".", "tmp"); // produce a temporary file name, in the current directory


if(!$input = fopen($csvfile,'r'))
{
    die('could not open existing csv file');
}

if(!$output = fopen($tempfile,'w'))
{
    die('could not open temporary output file');
}


while(($data = fgetcsv($input)) !== FALSE)
{

    $sku = trim($data[0]);



// get product by product sku 
$product = $productRepository->get($sku);

    $data[1] = $product->getPrice();
    $data[2] = $product->getQty();

    fputcsv($output,$data);
}

fclose($input);
fclose($output);
rename($tempfile,$csvfile);

echo  done;